# jquery dynamic change of value to select box not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a kind of stuck as everything else is working fine for me but when I try to get the value of my select dropdown from jquery, it still shows the selected value (value set prior to the new value).
Have gone through [jquery dropdown change](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-dynamically-select-option-in-dropdown-menu) and a couple more but they didn't help much, probably I'm not accessing the right property.

```
<select name="RP_6199" class="form-control" id="RP_6199">
    <option value="-1">Unknown</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">B</option><!--currently selected value-->
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

The code I'm doing is

```
 $("select[name=rp_" + individual.type + "]").each(function () {
     individual.rpId = $("select[name=rp_" + individual.type + "] option:selected").val();
 });
```

please ignore any naming errors as i have just replaced the original names by some other names for confidentiality.
Somehow, the selected value I'm getting here is still showing the old option, though I have changed the option.

Comment: use `change event` not `.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#RP_6199').change(function(){
alert($('option:selected',this).val())

}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="RP_6199" class="form-control" id="RP_6199">
    <option value="-1">Unknown</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option selected='selected' value="2">B</option><!--currently selected value-->
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

1. Use `.change()`
2. Call change event manually to show the value of selected option on load
3. Wrap the code in document ready